# Deleting specific lines in a file in C

Tags: c, file, input

Current deleting part of the code.

```
printf("Opening input and output file... ");
    if ((ifp = fopen("baza.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! input file open error.");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((ofp = fopen("baza.txt", "w")) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! output file open error");
        exit(1);
    }
printf("OK\n");
printf("Updating file... ");
    rewind(ofp);            
    rewind(ifp);            
    i = 0;
    while (!feof(ifp)){
        if (ftell(ifp) == point[i]){
            i++;
            for (s = 0; s < 5; s++)
                fgets(buffer, 30, ifp);
        }
        fgets(buffer, 30, ifp);
        fputs(buffer, ofp); fputs("\n", baza);
    }
printf("OK\n");
printf("Closing input and output files... ");
    rewind(ifp);
    rewind(ofp);
    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
printf("OK\n");
```

Text file:

```
Samsung
Galaxy Mini 2
250
14
-
HTC
One X
350
25
-
Sony
XPERIA
300
9
-
HUAWEI
Ascend Y530
116
9
-
```

Just to get a couple of thing clear first. There is already a part of the code which finds a specific input (since this is a "mobile store" console app, the user can search for a developer, model, price or amount of items currently in the store, followed by a separator between each phone information '-'.

So say a user is searching for a mobile price 350, it will jump to the first price, compare, just 5 lines, compare, etc. If it finds the right value, it stores the position of '-' above it (special case for first item, since it only has a blank space instead of '-'. **ALL THIS UNTIL NOW WORKS FINE**, which is why I didn't include that code.

The problem begins when I try to delete a certain phone from the library. What I had in mind is that it opens up the file in 2 modes, read and write, and rewinds both to beginning (just in case). Now because the "baza.txt" file is empty due to opening in w (ofp), but it's still contained in ifp - r, I shuffle through the ifp FILE and import everything to ofp except when the pointer reaches the array location of point.

**-> The only problem I've got** is that when I open this text file, I can only find the last line of the previous file. It looks like it contantly draws in the text on first line, never skipping to the second. In a+ mode this works fine, but the problem is that in a+ mode it doesn't delete the content, leaving a mess in the file - duplicates, leftovers etc. since the file gets shrinked.

I also tried closing ofp as soon as I opened it (since it's an empty file now) and opening it in a+, but the compiler doesn't like that, apparently.

Sorry for the long post

Tl/Dr. Read from the **->** above.

Comment: Why are you using a text file for this sort of thing? Why not a proper database?

Comment: Because it's a college assignment where I have to use a text file :) I agree it's pointless, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't open the same file for both reading and writing *separately*, the second `fopen` call will truncate the file and therefore you will loose all content.

Instead the usual way to handle your case is to write to a temporary file, and when done rename the temporary file as the original file.

As a side-note, don't do `while (!feof(...))`, it will in most cases not work as you expect it to, because the end-of-file flag will not be set until *after* you try to read from beyond the end of the file, and you will iterate the loop one extra time. Instead do e.g. `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`.

Comment: One way to fix it is to open the file for reading, unlink/remove it and then open it for writing. That way you can continue to read the old content until you close `ifp` because the output will be a brand new file located somewhere else on the disk. Most people still go with a temporary file, because that way your file won't be destroyed in case of errors.

Comment: Yeah, I went for the temporary file just to see if I'll have the same response as earlier (only last line), but it worked out pretty nicely. Now I write it to temp-baza.txt then transfer that back to baza.txt... But I'm interested, doesn't the file "sustain" itself in r mode? Or does it get deleted as well if the file in w is overwritten? Regardless, thank you all for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should never open a file from which you want to read in `w+` mode, because you will truncate it before reading. At best you can keep what the system or the library put in cache but it is underterminated behaviour.

As you rewind `ofp` file before reading, you should open it in `a+` mode, but `r+` would even be better since it gives pointer initially positionned at beginning of file. To solve the problem of garbage at end of file you simply have to truncate `ofp` at current offset just before closing it, of course without rewinding !

The end of your program should be :

```
printf("OK\n");
printf("Closing input and output files... ");
    off_t offset = ftell(ofp);
    ftruncate(ofp, offset);
    /* rewind(ifp); useless
    rewind(ofp); */
    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
printf("OK\n");
```